# The .replaceWholeText() method is obsoleted, what other methods can do this?

Tags: javascript, html

Text node method `replaceWholeText()` is obsoleted, what other methods can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`parentNode.normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/normalize) method in order to remove all empty and adjacent TextNodes (i.e you will have only one TextNode made of the `wholeText`), and then set your merged TextNode's textContent to the replaced value:

```js
const para = document.querySelector('p');
para.appendChild(new Text('baz')); // would remain if not normalized

console.log('before normalizing');
console.log('textContent: ', para.firstChild.textContent);
console.log('wholeText: ',para.firstChild.wholeText);

para.normalize();
console.log('after normalizing');
console.log('textContent: ', para.firstChild.textContent);
console.log('wholeText: ',para.firstChild.wholeText);

// now we can set the wholeText to whatever we want.
para.firstChild.textContent = 'Hello world';
```

```html
<p>
foo bar
</p>
```

Comment: tks, parentNode.normalize() help me solve the question of mutil adjacent  text node 。

Answer (score 0):

There are two modern alternatives to [`replaceWholeText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text/replaceWholeText):

1. **[`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)**:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = 'Two';
```

```html
<p>One</p>
```

2. **[`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)**:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].textContent = 'Two';
```

```html
<p>One</p>
```

`.textContent` is preferred, for the following reasons:

- it has better performance (because its value is not parsed as HTML)
- it can prevent XSS attacks
- it gets the content of *all* elements (including `<script>` and `<style>` elements)
- it returns every element in the node (including those with no content)
- it doesn't *permanently destroy* all descendant text nodes in Internet Explorer

Comment: TextNodes don't have an `innerHTML` property.  How could this be the *intended successor*?

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion appears to be to use [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). It appears to do the same thing as replaceWholeText.

> element.innerHTML = content;
>   Removes all of element's children, parses the content string and assigns the resulting nodes as children of the element.

Answer (score 0):

*textNode* inherits from *characterData* (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CharacterData) class, which has dynamic writable *data* property:

```
document.createTextNode('Original text').data = "replaced text';
```